# Force Nokia Black update

Tags: lumia-black-update

Is there any way to force the Nokia Black update on a Lumia 1020?

I know I should wait for my carrier to approve it first but that is where the problem comes in. You see my Lumia was a gift from Nokia South Africa and if I look in "extras + info" (see below) I see that it is a "mea" (Middle East & Africa I guess) model with no carrier listed. I therefore cannot find it on Nokia's Black update release status page because there is no country for "mea". Considering it therefore has no carrier to approve the update I guess I should already be able to get it but unfortunately my phone says that no update is available, I am therefore guessing that I will never get the update the official way. Does anyone know of an unofficial way?

[image]

Comment: This is just IMHO, but isn't Mobile operator `000-55` responsible for pushing upgrade?

Comment: @mpapec I have never heard of such an operator, any idea how I can determine if this is a real operator and what their name is?

Comment: perhaps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code

Comment: Shouldn't the "country variant"-update apply to you?

Comment: Any updates, @Gerhman? I'm in the same situation and I got tired of checking for updates with no result...

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have figured out that my device is a generic model for quite a few countries in the Middle East, all of which have not yet received the Black update. I will try using this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2515453 tutorial to change my phone to a South African model which as it may happen do already have the update. I know this can void my warranty but I doubt they will respect my warranty at the moment here in South Africa if it has firmware for the Middle East...

Answer (score -2):

Till your mobile operator pushes it out for your handset the only option is to do it yourself,
http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-8-update-3-update-your-handset-today

Comment: Installing Update 3 doesn't give you the Lumia Black extras.

Comment: Which extras? App Folder? Glance 2.0? Beamer 1.1? You can download those after you do the update.

Comment: GDR3 and Nokia Black update are different

Comment: Update to GDR3 and then download and flash the firmare for Black onto your device